# WiFi Sync iPhone on new MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, iphone, itunes, macbook-pro, data-synchronization

I am able to sync when the iPhone is connected by cable, although its not possible through WiFi.

On my previous mac, the iPhone would be visible in iTunes at all times while both connected to WiFi.

Although now its not visible whether its connected to power source or not. Also from the iPhone my MBP doesn't appear available. Both devices are registered under same Apple ID.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Connect your iPhone to iTunes and select it when it shows up in the sidebar.
2. Scroll down in the Summary Pane until you see the "Options"
3. Assure that the "Sync with this iPhone over Wi-Fi" option is checked.
4. Click the "Apply" button and you're done.

[image: iTunes iPhone Summary-> Options]

Comment: that was a no-brainer...wonder how i missed it. thanks